# How do I remove the group name in the QGIS legend renderer

Tags: qgis, printing

I am using QGIS 2.8.1 and the print composer to create a map for export. There is a lot of positive things to be said about the QGIS print composer. It gives the user good access to the rendering.

I want the legend to render without the group name. In this example I have two categories of protected areas I want to keep in the legend. The two categories are from the same spatial data source, in this case a shapefile with attributes making it possible to categorize styling. In short I do not want the text "Protected areas" in my legend.

[image]

In ArcGIS the below dialogue box alows for this functionality.

[image]

How can I do this in QGIS (2.8.1)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the item in the legend and you have a range of options to control how that item is shown:

[image]